# Browser navigates to webpage, but I get 500 error when using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I need to send a request to a webpage.  In the past, I have used HttpURLConnection, and everything worked fine.  When I try to do the same thing this time, I get a 500 return code.  Usually, this means a problem on the server, but I can actually paste the url directly into a web browser, and I get there with no problem.  (The browser is not loading a cached version.)

```
java.net.URL myURL = new java.net.URL(STRING_OF_URL_TO_BE_VISITED);
java.net.HttpURLConnection connection = (java.net.HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestMethod("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0");

connection.connect();

Integer responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

String headerItem = "";
String headerKey = "";

for(Integer i = 0; ; i++)
{
    headerKey = connection.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
    headerItem = connection.getHeaderField(i);
    if(headerKey == null)
        headerKey = "";
    else
        headerKey += ": ";
    if(headerItem == null)
        break;

    System.out.println(headerKey + headerItem);
}
```

The response header looks like

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en-US
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; Path=/webapps/myWebApp; Secure
X-appserver: myserver.mydomain.com
P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"
Date: Thu, 31 Jul 2014 19:24:19 GMT
Content-Length: 25912
```

A co-worker thought that maybe the webpage was trying to re-direct to another webpage, but I don't see a Location line in the header, so I don't know how it would be redirecting.

I've tried keeping the connection alive and listening for another response, but I never get another one.

Comment: What's the content of the response?

Comment: If I try to access the `HttpURLConnection`'s `InputStream`, then I get an `IOException`.  The `ErrorStream` has a bunch of `<script>` tags in it. It looks like a bunch of javascript that validates fields that the user would type into.

Comment: Can you capture your failing HttpURLConnection GET request in Fiddler?

Comment: I haven't read all of your code, but `connection.setRequestMethod("Mozilla/5.0");` is non-sense. Read the API and have a look at some samples.

Comment: @hgoebl I accidentally deleted "User-Agent" from that function when copying from my workstation to the text editor.  I have updated the code.

Comment: Looks like if I run the get request in Fiddler, I get a 302 that redirects to a page that gives a 500.  If, instead, I paste the request into the web browser, I get a sequence of 200's.

Comment: Setting `connection.setRequestMethod("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0");` is non-sense, too.

Comment: Well, it's worked before and wouldn't cause a 500 error, so obviously that's not the area of focus.  But thanks for the helpful comment.

Comment: I ended up achieving the ultimate goal by navigating to two separate pages.  Funny, the `setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0")` did not bother anything.  Imagine that.